# Date().getTime() JavaScript convert to php?

Tags: javascript, php

I have this jquery function to get date diference.

```
  function distance(date) {
    return (new Date().getTime() - date.getTime());
  }
```

I tried to convert this new date() to php:

```
  function distance(date) {
    return (<?php echo time(); ?> - date.getTime());
  }
```

this way I could get server date instead of user date. but it is wrong cause the time diference become 49 years.
any ideas why?

Comment: PHP times are seconds, JavaScript times are milliseconds.

Comment: FYI, `Date` is ordinary JavaScript, not related to jQuery.

Answer (score 5):

In php `time()` returns the time in seconds. (in unix time)

While in Javascript it is returned in milliseconds.

Your solution would be to convert php time in milliseconds.

```
function distance(date) {
  return (<?php echo time()*1000; ?> - date.getTime());
}
```